# sum one field inside of a linq query traversing the data structure

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

I have two datatables:

1 - billing_transactions

2- billing_transaction_accessorial_charge

They are related by billing_transactions.Id equals billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.billing_transactions_id

Each billing transaction can have multiple accessorial charges.
I need to sum them up in order to return them to a datagrid.
I have tried multiple ways and just can't get it done.
I don't mind using a join if needed, but the relationship is setup and works.

The field I need summed is called billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.amount and is a decimal.

Here is my main query:

```
 var gridData = (from d in db.billing_transactions
                        where d.status == 1
                        select new
                        {
                            d.base_amount,
                            d.Id,
                            drivers_name = d.stop_details.driver_details.first_name + " " + d.stop_details.driver_details.last_name,
                            d.billing_note,
                            d.correcting_entry,
                            d.fuel_surcharge,
                            d.invoice_number,
                            d.net_amount,
                            d.original_billing_transaction_id,
                            d.pcs_billed,
                            billing_transactions_status = d.status,
                            billing_transaction_status_desc = d.billing_lookup_transaction_status_names.status,
                            d.customer_id,
                            d.rule_id,
                            d.weight_billed,
                            d.stop_details.con_name,
                            d.stop_details.con_address1,
                            d.stop_details.con_city,
                            d.stop_details.con_state,
                            d.stop_details.con_zip,
                            d.stop_details.assigned_driver_id,
                            d.stop_details.billing_base_rate,
                            d.stop_details.billing_geoZone_id,
                            d.stop_details.billing_weight_class_id,
                            d.stop_details.cust_ref_1_BOL,
                            d.stop_details.cust_ref_2_OrderNum,
                            d.stop_details.cust_ref_3_stopID,
                            d.stop_details.cust_ref_4_routeID,
                            d.stop_details.cust_ref_5_terminalID,
                            d.stop_details.items_del_ytd,
                            d.stop_details.lading_qty_haz,
                            d.stop_details.lading_qty_total,
                            d.stop_details.lading_wgt_haz,
                            d.stop_details.lading_wgt_total,
                            d.stop_details.note_from_cust,
                            d.stop_details.pallets_qty_total,
                            d.stop_details.pallets_wgt_total,
                            d.stop_details.ship_date,
                            stop_status = d.stop_details.status,
                            d.stop_details.stop_canceled,
                            d.stop_details.stop_changed,
                            d.stop_details.verified_ship_date,
                            d.stop_details.verified_timestamp,
                            d.stop_details.wgt_del_ytd,
                            d.customer.customer_name,
                            count = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Count,
                            placeholder1 = ""
                        }
                      ).ToArray();
```

Comment: Similar to `Count()`, you can use  `Sum` (`amount = d.billing_transaction_accessorial_charge.Sum(c => c.amount)`), what's the issue?

Comment: `sum = d.billing_transcation_accessorial_charge.Sum(a => a.amount)`?

Comment: I don't know.  I would have sworn I tried that exact code and it kept coming up with wrong answers.  But yes, that is simple and works.  Maybe I need the second cup of coffee.....

Comment: I *really* appreciate the help.  trying to get code out before the customer gets in and had a brain fart...both of the comments work, I can't answer the question yet.  but will accept either of them if you just post it as a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't have enough rep to post in comment section...
What if you try this ?

```
var query = (from bt in db.billing_transactions
             where bt.status == 1
             join btac in db.billing_transaction_accessioral_charge on bt.Id equals btac.billing_transactions_id
             select new {
                amount = btac.Sum(x => x.amount)
}).Distinct().ToList();
```

**EDIT** Idk why you want to avoid join, but this should do the job without join (haven't tested it):

```
var query = (from bt in db.billing_transactions
                 where bt.status == 1
                 select new {
                    amount = btac.billing_transaction_accessioral_charge.Sum(x => x.amount)
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Florian....one of the comments answered it (well both of them) with no need for a join.  If somebody writes it up as a answer I will accept it.  Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Indeed, I saw a bit late... hehe :-)